# Отправка сообщения от телеграмм бота когда переменная достигнет определённого значения

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я пишу сигнально телеграмм бота который должен отправлять сообщение когда переменная достигает определённого значения но просто командой bot.send_message это не работает
Использую библиотек pyTelegrambotapi

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для точного ответа на ваш вопрос нужно видеть код, потому что это делатеся как раз функцией `bot.send_message()`.

Данный код отправит сообщение как только значение переменной `i` станет равным 5:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('ваш_токен')

for i in range(10):

    if i == 5:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'сообщение')
    
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Важно понимать, что для отправки сообщения нужно знать id чата для передачи в функцию. Его вы можете либо получить из хэндлера `@bot.message_handler()`, либо указать напрямую для отправки в конкретный чат. Это зависит от ваших задач и без вашего кода ответить точно нельзя